# Android shouldOverrideUrlLoading does not get called in KitKat 4.4.3

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, android-webview

I've been using shouldOverrideUrlLoading successfully in 4.4.2 on my Android devices. The same application on the newer version of KitKat (4.4.3) doesn't call the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method at all!

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested this just yesterday, and it was working. Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce this?

Comment: Our application uses JavaScript for a button to change shape when pressed and then shouldOverrideUrlLoading should catch this change to do something else. It would be difficult to give an example here. I am just wondering if anything has changed from the previous OS version to the new 4.4.3?

Comment: Write a bare minimum webview based app that points to a page you control.  

Put a "special URL" (/test/this) on the page. In your Android app, check for this String in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. Attach a debugger, or have it `Toast` something out. Confirm it works on an older device.

Comment: Yes, the version of Chrome the WebView is based on has changed. What are the URLs that you're using? What's the pages base URL (window.location.toString()) and what's the path (link that you're expecting to see in shouldOverrideUrlLoading)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that WebView from android version 4.4.3 doesn't support custom url schema properly. I don't know is this bug or feature.

```
href="myschem://calback"
```

Click on this href doesn't call the android's callback method:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

}
```

To call this callback href have to begin from "`http`", so replace all your href to:

```
 href="http://calback"
```

And you app will work.

Comment: This usually should work, according to the official Android-documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs) . Here is already a bug-report filed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66675